# Specify list of server.port for java application

Tags: java, rest, port

Is there a way to specify a list of ports for a Tomcat to spin up Java application?
I know you can do server.port=9000 to specify a port number but is there a way to specify a list of ports for the app to run. Say if one is busy, it will automatically bind to other ports in the list?

Comment: May be this can help you https://tech.asimio.net/2016/12/15/Configuring-Tomcat-to-Listen-on-Multiple-ports-using-Spring-Boot.html

Comment: Yes, just specify more Connectors, but it will listen at them all. You shouldn't need to do this, and it won't work even if you succeed: the clients won't try to connect to successive ports, only to one.